The flutter project reported an error when running in VSCode. error: Invalid Swift parseable output message (malformed JSON): `[123, 10,
The flutter project runs fine in XCode, but an error occurs when running in VSCode.
error: Invalid Swift parseable output message (malformed JSON): `[123, 10,
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.27.1, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 3.27.1 on channel stable at /Users/gaoang/workPlace/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 17025dd882 (4 days ago), 2024-12-17 03:23:09 +0900
    • Engine revision cb4b5fff73
    • Dart version 3.6.0
    • DevTools version 2.40.2
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16B40
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2
[✓] VS Code (version 1.96.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.102.0

Detailed error information
-emit-module-source-info-path
/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-arajkifbwnbnviffhwcnsvblxefw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/iot_plugins.build/Objects-normal/arm64/iot_plugins.swiftsourceinfo
-emit-objc-header-path
/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-arajkifbwnbnviffhwcnsvblxefw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/iot_plugins.build/Objects-normal/arm64/iot_plugins-Swift.h
-serialize-diagnostics-path
/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-arajkifbwnbnviffhwcnsvblxefw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/iot_plugins.build/Objects-normal/arm64/iot_plugins-master-emit-module.dia
-emit-dependencies-path
/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-arajkifbwnbnviffhwcnsvblxefw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/iot_plugins.build/Objects-normal/arm64/iot_plugins-master-emit-module.d
-parse-as-library -o
/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-arajkifbwnbnviffhwcnsvblxefw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/iot_plugins.build/Objects-normal/arm64/iot_plugins.swiftmodule
-emit-abi-descriptor-path
/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-arajkifbwnbnviffhwcnsvblxefw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/iot_plugins.build/Objects-normal/arm64/iot_plugins.abi.json
error: Invalid Swift parseable output message (malformed JSON): `[123, 10, 32, 32, 34, 107, 105, 110, 100, 34, 58, 32, 34, 102, 105, 110, 105, 115, 104, 101, 100, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 110, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32,34, 101, 109, 105, 116, 45, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 112, 105, 100, 34, 58, 32, 50, 54, 48, 52, 54, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 111, 117, 116, 112, 117, 116, 34, 58, 32, 34, 60, 109, 111, 100,117, 108, 101, 45, 105, 110, 99, 108, 117, 100, 101, 115, 62, 58, 49, 58, 57, 58, 32, 110, 111, 116, 101, 58, 32, 105, 110, 32, 102, 105, 108, 101, 32, 105, 110, 99, 108, 117, 100, 101, 100, 32, 102, 114, 111, 109,32, 60, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101, 45, 105, 110, 99, 108, 117, 100, 101, 115, 62, 58, 49, 58, 92, 110, 35, 105, 109, 112, 111, 114, 116, 32, 92, 34, 72, 101, 97, 100, 101, 114, 115, 92, 47, 105, 111, 116, 95, 112,........

